# Find length of json string

Tags: javascript, json

I have following Jsonstring

```
  var j = { "name": "John" };
            alert(j.length);
```

it alerts : undefined, How can i find the length of json Array object??

Thanks

Comment: That isn't a "json Array object", it's a string literal that creates an object.

Comment: isn't it considered a json object?

Comment: @RPM—No. [JSON](http://www.json.org/) is "JavaScript Object Notation" that is based on ECMAScript object literal notation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lets start with the json string:

```
var jsonString = '{"name":"John"}';
```

you can easily determine its length:

```
alert("The string has "+jsonString.length+" characters"); // will alert 15
```

Then parse it to an object:

```
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

A JavaScript [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) [is not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and has no length. If you want to know how many properties it has, you will need to count them:

```
var propertyNames = Object.keys(jsonObject);
alert("There are "+propertyNames.length+" properties in the object"); // will alert 1
```

If `Object.keys`, the function to get an `Array` with the (own) property names from an `Object`, is not available in your environment (older browsers etc.), you will need to count manually:

```
var props = 0;
for (var key in jsonObject) {
    // if (j.hasOwnProperty(k))
    /* is only needed when your object would inherit other enumerable
       properties from a prototype object */
        props++;
}
alert("Iterated over "+props+" properties"); // will alert 1
```

Comment: Hey, would you mind editing the question to make it clear what it's talking about? I bet you know the subject matter better than I do and would do a better job of it. Thanks!

Comment: You mentioned something about JSON array vs normal JSON object in your flag?

Comment: JSON is just the serialisation. Yet, JS objects are more like maps/dictionaries, and Arrays are special objects with enumeration. So, the example object the OP asked about is not an Array.

Answer (score 4):

Another way of doing this is to use the later `JSON.stringify` method which will give you an object (a string) on which you can use the `length` property:

```
var x = JSON.stringify({ "name" : "John" });

alert(x.length);
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4yf5R/)

Comment: You're right, he asked for "*length of json string*", but I guess that's not what he wanted...

Comment: Thanks @Bergi. You can always upvote my answer if you really think it's right :)

Answer (score 3):

```
function getObjectSize(o) {
  var c = 0;
  for (var k in o) 
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(k)) ++c;
  return c;
}  
var j = { "name": "John" };

alert(getObjectSize(j)); // 1
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no json Array object in javascrit. `j` is just an object in javascript.

If you means the number of properties the object has(exclude the prototype's), you could count it by the below way:

```
  var length = 0;
  for (var k in j) {
    if (j.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      length++;
    }
  }
  alert(length);
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate in Jquery:

```
 var myObject = {"jsonObj" : [    
        {
            "content" : [
                {"name" : "John"},
            ]
        }
        ]
       }
        $.each(myObject.jsonObj, function() {
           alert(this.content.length);
        });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9D5Eu/41/)

Comment: okay but this involes jquery. He never mentioned jquery in his question

Comment: @RPM oops! okay..let this be an alternate if the user prefers to use Jquery.

Comment: haha. no man its cool. As soon as I wrote my answer I had to check if I was using any jQuery functions. I'm so used to using jQuery.